# how to move from one pin to another in google map click event in html

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

i have displayed multiple pins in google map with infoWindows,and there location name displayed in html page, now i need this when click on any location name moving pins from one to another, and have show it's infoWindow.
so, is there any solution?
http://i53.tinypic.com/hvec15.jpg
Here is my code

```
function initialize() {


if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.50015, -0.12624), 13);

// Creates a marker at the given point
// Clicking the marker will hide it
var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(lat, longt));
    map.addOverlay(marker);
function createMarker(latlng, number) {
  var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
  marker.value = number;
  GEvent.addListener(marker,"click", function() {
    var myHtml =  number + "";
    map.openInfoWindowHtml(latlng, myHtml);
  });
  return marker;
}

// Add 5 markers to the map at random locations
// Note that we don't add the secret message to the marker's instance data
var bounds = map.getBounds();
for (index in markers){
var n=markers[index];
  var latlng = new GLatLng(n.lat,n.lng);
map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng, n.name));
}
marker.openInfoWindowHtml(WINDOW_HTML); 


 }
}
```

Comment: actually, i need like that, i displayed location name in html page, when click on that any of name, the location's pin displayed in map with infoWindow. i don't have to click in map

Comment: which version of google map your are using v2 or v3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i got it with google map_lib,
see demo: [login to see demo](http://wirkochenfair.ch/fairtrade/index.php)